# PowerShell foreach loop prints too much: I want it to print only what I want to print

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell I want to loop through an object that had several items in it, but I only want to look at two of the items, path and name, and do some logic on them. The problem is, if I use `foreach` or `ForEach-Object`, it immediately prints out `$line.Name` and `$line.Path` when I don't want them to print.

Tried `foreach` and `ForEach-Object`, tried `void` and `| Out-Null`, tried `$element.Name.ToString()`.

`void` and `Out-Null` pretty much wipes out the entire thing so I don't see any values, and I can still see blank lines where the `void` or `Out-Null` lines were at.

The `ToString()` still prints the value.

```cs
foreach ($line in $buildPipelineObject) {
    # $line.* has leading and trailing spaces, want to trim them
    $trimPath = $line.Path  # don't print!
    $trimPath.Trim()
    $trimName = $line.Name.ToString()  # don't print!
    #[void]Set-Variable -Name "trimName" -Value $line.Name # makes trimName null 
    $trimName.Trim()

    # if pipeline isn't in a subfolder, then I don't need to insert backslash
    if ($trimPath -eq "\") {
        $pipelineName = $trimPath + $trimName
    } else {
        $pipelineName = $trimPath + "\" + $trimName
    }
    Write-Host "pipeline: $pipelineName"
}
```

Problem is, I run this block, and I see stuff like

```
\
pipelinename1
pipeline: \pipelinename1
\myfolder
pl2
pipeline: \myfolder\pl2
```

I only want to see the "pipeline:" lines outputted, like

```
pipeline: \pipelinename1
pipeline: \myfolder\pl2
```

Comment: `$trimPath.Trim()` doesn't trim in place, it _returns_ a trimmed _copy_ of the string, which is _implicitly output_. Also, don't use `Write-Host` to output _data_, only use it to print to the display. E.g., use just `"pipeline: $pipelineName"` (which is implicitly like using `Write-Output`: `Write-Output "pipeline: $pipelineName"`)

Comment: the write-host was to print to the display.  And this doesn't really solve my problem, which I really only want to see pipeline: pipelinename. How can I NOT see $line.name and $line.path?

Comment: To prevent a statement that produces output from displaying / being sent to the pipeline, precede it with `$null = ...`. If you want to capture the trimmed string in a variable, use `$trimPath = $line.path.Trim()`, for instance. Note that _not_ using `Write-Host` _also_ prints to the display - but not _directly_, but via the _success output stream_ - to learn about PowerShell's output streams, see [about_redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection)

Comment: woohoo!!! thank you!!!

Comment: forgot to add what i did (which is what you implied.)

Comment: $null = $trimmedName = $line.path.Trim()

Comment: Also put it in a separate function (which does not write-host), returned the value which I then write-host'd.  it now works exactly as I wanted!

Comment: Glad to hear it; note that variable assignments never produce implicit output, so `$trimmedName = $line.path.Trim()` is sufficient - no need to prefix it with `$null = ` (which is itself an assignment - just to the special `$null` variable, which effectively _discards_ the output).

Comment: Why don't you just process the lines that you are interessted in? Something like this `foreach ($line in $buildPipelineObject | Where {$_.Path -like 'pipe*'})`

Comment: because the value of $_.path typically doesn't have the name 'pipe*'. path is just a folder path to where the pipeline actually exists, and the folder path can have any kind of name at all (including none, which is the "\").